# Actualize repository group

Tags: maven, repository, nexus, sonatype

I created a repository group and linked a few other hosted repositories under that : one release repo, and another snaphost repo.

I noticed that group repository is out of sync with the linked repositories: contains such snapshot artifacts (old, not used) which does not exist under my snapshot repository - since I created a scheduled task to clean up snapshots older then 14 days in.

In this case I always delete the problematic folder on the filesystem and then, and when I run a maven build next time using that public group repository url, artifacts get fetched and up to date versions can be seen then.

**To make it more clear**

Hi,I am trying to explain the situation. I have a Jenkins job, which had published an artifact with version eg. 3.28-SNAPSHOT to the snapshot repo before. Since I have snapshot and release hosted repos, I created a repo group and add these to it. Then some changes were done on the mentioned Jenkins job and version number (build number) started from 0 agagin (3.0-SNAPSHOT)... 
From this point of view the lower versions point to the newer artifacts and the higher versions point to the older ones. As I mentioned I have also a houskeeping script: shell script, not nexus scheduled task due to that is a littlebit slow, which deletes the snapshots older than 14 days + then I run update index nexus scheduled task to make local storage and nexus in sync . 
After this clean up those versions with 3.28-... were deleted from snapshot repo, but these outdated artifacts remained under the repository group. So my question comes from this point: Why artifacts are duplicated (I mean on the local storage consuming disk space) when I create a repository group pointing to other repositories (release, snapshot)?
How can I force not to copy each artifact from the linked repos, just to maintain a metadata where requested artifacts can be downloaded from? Or if it is not possible since the implementation does not support it, how can I resync my repository group to follow snapshot and release repo changes (clean up shell script + update index outcome)?

How can I resolve this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nothing is needed to keep a group repository in sync with it's member repositories, it's automatic.  Exactly what files are you seeing in it?

Comment: Some explanation was added to the description. I hope it will be more clear right now. Thanks!